# Permission issue when deploying Serverless Python app

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless

I have a Serverless Python app and I am trying to deploy it using sls deploy. The serverless.yml is as follows.

```
service: update-register

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.8
  profile: haumi
  stage: ${opt:stage, 'staging'}
  environment: ${file(environment.yml):${self:provider.stage}}
  region: ${self:provider.environment.REGION}

  iamRoleStatements:
    # para poder leer y escribir en el bucket
    - Effect: "Allow"
      Action:
        - "sqs:SendMessage"
      Resource: "*"

functions:
  update:
    handler: handler.update
    events:
      - sqs: ${self:provider.environment.AWS_SQS_QUEUE}
```

The handler file is like this:

```
def update(event, context):
    print("=== event: ", event)
```

However when I try to deploy and trigger the update function the following error appears in AWS Cloudwatch

```
[ERROR] PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/task/handler.py'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/imp.py", line 300, in find_module
    with open(file_path, 'rb') as file:
```

I tried changing the permissions of this file but I can't. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue had nothing to do with Serverless but with the permissions of my mounted NTFS partition in Ubuntu 18.04.

tl;dr
Change /etc/fstab to of the mounted partition to

```
UUID=8646486646485957 /home/Data      ntfs    defaults,auto,umask=002,uid=1000,gid=1000 0       0
```

Use id -u  to get the uid and gid.

**The long explanation**

What I found out is that in an NTFS partition you cannot just change a file permissions with chmod. You require to configure the mask while mounting the partition. Since I mount the partition upon booting Ubuntu, the required change was in my fstab file. The umask parameter determines which permissions **cannot be set**. You can find more information about this parameter [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18139/how-to-write-an-fstab-line-for-full-access-to-an-ntfs-drive).

After you do this reboot. You will find that the files have a different permission. In my case the permissions that allowed my deployed code to work were

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 user group   59 jul 24 00:47 handler.py*
```

I am sure there are issues by allowing others to execute the file. But this solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Another cause for the exact same error:

```
[ERROR] PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/task/<my_lambda_python_file>.py'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/imp.py", line 300, in find_module
    with open(file_path, 'rb') as file:
```

I was deploying the Lambda using Atlassian Bamboo, and Bamboo seemed to be messing with the permissions of the files that make up the lambda:

```
-rw-r-----@  1 <user>  <group>   2.5K 19 Nov 18:10 <my_lambda_python_file>.py
```

I worked around this problem by adding to the Bamboo script:

```
chmod 755 <my_lambda_python_file>.py
```

just before bundling the code into a zip file.